# How to use the setElem in Haskell to update the Matrix

Tags: haskell, matrix

I'm trying to use the function setElem in Haskell to update the Matrix, but seems the new value does not stay in the matrix. Is there a way to use this function to go around this problem?

I'm new with Haskell and what I need is to set a new value in the matrix and then show the matrix updated.

setElem :: a -> (Int, Int) -> Matrix a -> Matrix a

My code:

```
import Data.Matrix
import System.Random
import System.IO 
import Data.Array



table_game = matrix 20 20 $ \(i,j)-> "#"


inputCoordenadas = do       
            putStrLn "Digite -1 -1 para encerrar: "
            putStrLn "Digite a coordenada X: "
            coord_x <- getLine
            putStrLn "Digite a coordenada Y: "
            coord_y <- getLine
            let x = (read coord_x :: Int)
            let y = (read coord_y :: Int)
            if(coord_x == "-1"  && coord_y=="-1") then do 
                putStrLn ("Encerrando o jogo...")
                return ()
            else do 
                print $ setElem "X" (2,2) table_game
                print table_game
                inputCoordenadas


main = do   
    putStrLn "Iniciar jogo|1 - Encerrar jogo|0: "
    buffer <- getLine
    let n = (read buffer :: Int)    


if n==0 then do 
        putStrLn "Encerrando o jogo"
        return ()
 else do
    print table_game
    inputCoordenadas
```

Comment: So what's your question? Is your code not working? If so, how? Are you getting any errors? Are you getting incorrect results? Something else?

Comment: Yes, if you run the code and update some coordinates, and then input others x y to update, you'll see that the previous update was lost. That's my problem, how to make the update permanent in the matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell uses pure functions. Pure functions can not modify anything out of their context and prevent side effects. What you are trying is a sin in Haskell. Setting a global variable and trying to mutate it is a no no.

You are basically expected to structure your code such that the `inputCoordenadas` function takes a table-game (`tg` in my code below), prints it, modifies it and returns a new table-game. With minimal change your code should be like

```
import Data.Matrix
import System.Random
import System.IO 
import Data.Array

inputCoordenadas tg = do
    print tg
    putStrLn "Digite -1 -1 para encerrar: "
    putStrLn "Digite a coordenada X: "
    coord_x <- getLine
    putStrLn "Digite a coordenada Y: "
    coord_y <- getLine
    let x = (read coord_x :: Int)
    let y = (read coord_y :: Int)
    if(coord_x == "-1"  && coord_y=="-1") then putStrLn "Encerrando o jogo..."
                                          else inputCoordenadas $ setElem "X" (x,y) tg

main = do
    putStrLn "Iniciar jogo|1 - Encerrar jogo|0: "
    buffer <- getLine
    let n = (read buffer :: Int)
    if n==0 then  putStrLn "Encerrando o jogo"
            else  inputCoordenadas $ matrix n n (\(i,j) -> "#")
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wan to do. Sorry for the mistakes in the code, but I'm really new with Haskell, and I'm trying to get the functional paradigm thing, but I've been in languages such C/C++ for the past years. This a project I have to delivery to university tomorrow, at least this part I think was fixed. Then I need to go with random numbers in that matrix. The final project will be a minesweeper game, a simple one. Thank you very much for the feedback!

Comment: For the next phase you need the `randomRIO` function like `randomRIO (1,n)` to place a mine randomly. To obtain random coordinates for `m` mines you may do like `zipWith (,) <$> (replicateM m $ randomRIO (1,n)) <*> (replicateM m $ randomRIO (1,n))` whereas `n` is the size of the board.

Comment: @Redu's solution might be a bit much to understand for a newbie -- there are a couple different concepts introduced at one.  But you can do it one by one like they said with `x <- randomRIO (1,n)`. The tricky bit is that this is an IO action-- you use it like `getLine` rather than like `read`.

Comment: What I thought due to the time I have, is to generate 40 coordinates (40 mines) and put them into some list, and then check in it if the user input matches the coordinates of having a bomb. But now, when I put a bomb in x y I have to put a value that shows that near that coordinates have a bomb or more. If I have a bomb placed in (2,2) and the user input is 2,1, I have to show that there is a bomb  right near or a blank space, just like the minesweeper. If you can help with some advice, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @Talles Silva It's already late here so i can only afford a hint before i sleep. By now you should know how to fill your table-game with 40 mines at random coordinates and also how you can update it with a new mine coordinate coming from the user. The beauty of immutability of the Matrix type (table-game) means that you can check the two game-tables (the one with the 40 random mines and the one obtained by user update) by the equality operator `(==)`. If they are equal then you can make sure that the player has hit a mine. If the user marks a mine-free cell you just carry on for another guess.

Comment: @Talles Silva and yes.. i know you have to update the free-cell to `show` the number of neighboring mines but then nobody stops you from writing a function to traverse the neighbors and count the mines to be displayed. I thrust you can do it.

Comment: @Talles Silva Keep in mind that `zipWith (,) <$> (replicateM m $ randomRIO (1,n)) <*> (replicateM m $ randomRIO (1,n))` will give you `m` many random mines but it doesn't guarantee that they won't overlap. So you will possibly end up with less than `m` mines in your table-game. This is not related with Haskell but the nature of randomness. To eliminate this fact is possible in many ways but should be just fine as it is, for starters at least.

Comment: First I generate a list for the x-axis and then for the y-axis. Then I combine then in a list of ([a,b]). I'm trying to use the zipWith like you have recommended, because it sounds much better then the three functions above. But I just can't do this: let temp_list = zipWith (,) <$> (replicateM 40 $ randomRIO (1,20)) <*> (replicateM 40 $ randomRIO (1,20)), because an error arrises and I'm trying to figure it out why. e M the number of mines).

Comment: But the finally question, and I apprecitate very much for you have spent you time helping me, but how to use this coordinates in the matrix? I mean, I could use the setElem to place the bombs, but even I get the random coordinates for the zipWith, it's a list and I have to extract the pair (x,y) to pass it in the setElem in a recursive way (lik

Comment: @Talles Silva Fill your board with `m` **unique** mines as follows. `(,) <$> [1..n] <*> [1..n]`. This code will give you a list of all coordinates on your board like `[(1,1),(1,2)..(1,n),(2,1),(2,2)..(2,n)..(n,1),(n,2)..(n,n)]`. Now all coordinates are unique but they are useless since they are in order. Now [shuffle](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/232894/105433) this list and `take m` many coordinates from the list. `\n m -> take m . shuffle $ ((,) <$> [1..n] <*> [1..n])`. Now you have your perfecty random `m` many bomb coordinates. Use above code to insert the bombs in your board.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell does not have mutable variables.  The simplest (least abstract) way to do this is to add a parameter to your function:

```
inputCoordinadas tab = do
    ....
    let newTab = setElem "X" (x,y) tab
    inputCoordinadas newTab
```

So each time the function is called, it is called with the "current" table. When it calls itself, it passes an updated table.

There are fancier ways to do this but this solution is also fine and relatively common even among those who know the fancy ways.

Comment: Thanks for the replay! I'tried to pass the table to the function, but I don't if I'm doing some stupid procedure or it really does not work that way. I create a type called 

type Table = Matrix

then 

inputCoordinadas :: Tabuleiro -> Tabuleiro 

But seems not to work